# PHP uploading image does nothing, no error given

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, file-upload

I'm making a site where people can upload a profile image. The page redirects as if there's no error, and the SQL updates fine, but the image doesn't appear in its directory. The php.ini says it has permission to upload. Also, when I attempted the same thing on localhost it worked perfectly

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh.php';
$id = $_SESSION['userID'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = $_FILES['file'];

//about the file
$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $file['size'];
$fileError = $file['error'];
$fileType = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

  //checks if it's in the allowed type
      if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
          //checks for errors
          if ($fileError === 0) {
                //checks for appropriate file size
              if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                $sql = "UPDATE users SET profilePicture='$fileNameNew' WHERE userID='$id';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
              } else {
                  echo "Your file is too big!";
              }
          } else {
              echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
          }
      } else {
          echo "You must choose a valid file type!";
      }

}
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of the script will likely reveal `move_uploaded_file` is failing and why.

Comment: @drew010, this led me to my solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped you!  That tip will save you countless hours in the future, always remember it when you encounter issues during development.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path to the uploads directory.

```
$path = getcwd();
echo $path;

$fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
```

May end up looking like

`$fileDestination = '/home/user/public_html/uploads/'.$fileNameNew;`